# Comentários trocados

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Posso estar enganado, mas parece que os comentários da pergunta [«facto» ou «fato»?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/facto-ou-fato) estão na pergunta [Qual é a origem da expressão “foda-se” para expressar consternação](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3532/qual-%C3%A9-a-origem-da-express%C3%A3o-foda-se-para-expressar-consterna%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria algum *bug* no sistema?

Comment: Denis não estão trocados, alias foi desses comentários que nasceu a pergunta «facto» ou «fato»?.

Comment: Entendi, desculpe-me o transtorno.

Comment: Denis fizeste muito bem em reportar, poderia ser mesmo um bug.

Comment: Ah e o PL também tem meta como já deves ter reparado ;) 
http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sim, eu sei. Cadastrei a pergunta no site erro, mas vi que ela  foi migrada para o PL, muito legal.

Answer (score 3):

Parece-me que o primeiro comentário está a corrigir o uso de "fato" no penúltimo parágrafo (porque todo o post parece ser escrito em português europeu, à excepção do uso dessa palavra), e que isso gerou conversa à volta da palavra levar ou não o "c" em Portugal. Nada de errado aí, embora pareçam, de facto, fora de sítio.

Comment: JNat foi essa pequena discussão que gerou a pergunta [«facto» ou «fato»?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3533/153).